# how do i upload image on strapi for a specific user

Tags: reactjs, react-admin, strapi

I'm trying to upload an image from React Admin on Strapi for a specific user I've gone through the documentation but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First you have to go in the Content Type Builder on the left menu.

  - Then you click on the User content type to edit it.
  - You add a new field that is a `Media` type.
  - And you save your update

After that if you click on the User link in the left menu and that you try to add a new user you will be able to add an Image.